# how do I pass ratingbar value properly to Map

Tags: php, android, mysql

how should I pass the rating bar value properly to the Map so that it can be send online to mysql, the "lastname" part of the code it working its sending online Im just having problem with my rating bar. It doesnt show any error but it does not send any value to mysql.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText firstname, comment, age;
Button insert, show;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
String insertUrl = "http://192.168.1.2/insertStudent.php";
TextView result;
RatingBar ratingBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    comment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etComment);
    insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert);
    ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    final float rating = ratingBar.getRating();



    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());


    insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> parameters  = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    parameters.put("lastname",comment.getText().toString());
                    parameters.put("rating",String.valueOf(rating));
                    return parameters;
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }

    });


}

}
```

this is my php code

```
 <?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
require 'connection.php';
createStudent();
}


function createStudent()
{
global $connect;


$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
$age = $_POST["age"];

$query = " Insert into student(lastname,rating) values ('$lastname','$rating');";

mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
mysqli_close($connect);

}
```

?>

Comment: Please recheck your SQL query, you've only inserting 2 values (firstname and age but you've specified that 3 values will be inserted to 3 fields), maybe try the query like : $query = " Insert into student(firstname,age) values ('$firstname','$age');";

Comment: @RamithDR I deleted it purposely I dont think It affected the application. but thanks for the comment ill edit it.

Comment: @RamithDR it didnt solve thr problem but still thank you ^^

Comment: Oh alright, May I ask why you're using a rating bar to get user age?

Comment: Its not that. I just didnt change the name ill change it. It was before age and then I change some function of my system and added a rating bar, Im just trying to pass the value of the rating bar to the variable age passing it to my php code passing to my mysql database which didnt happen.